# How do I merge edges so that the merge creates vertices?

Tags: edges

I am trying to use blender to model walk-able area maps for a game. I am using very simple shapes and want the minimal triangle count as possible. Given this:

[image: two connected planes]

I want this end result:

[image: two connected planes, triangulated]

I accomplished this by snapping the angled plane to the flat one and then I subdivided the flat plane's edge twice and merged the vertices. This was finicky because I had to manually move the connected vertices to create a rectangle, and also because I had to manually subdivide the plane. Is there a way to connect the two edges in this manner without this process of subdivision + manual vertex adjustment?